# Java 'TimeoutException' can't be thrown or catched

Tags: java, android, timeoutexception

I am developing an android app that reads a webpage using *AsyncTask*.I have 2 AsyncTask classes that reads different page, one inside service, other not.In both cases *url connection* method is enclosed inside **try-catch** block , but their catch blocks are different(**TimeoutException** catch block missing in the 2nd **AsyncTask class**, tried to catch or throw it manually but failed) .Even though their connection methods are same, their **try-catch** blocks are different, but I need to catch **TimeoutException** in both task. 
Here is part of my 1st AsyncTask class

```
try {
    url=new URL(link);
    huc=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
    huc.setDoOutput(true);
    huc.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
    huc.connect();
    dothework();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    showErrorMsg();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and part of 2nd AsyncTask class

```
try {
    url = new URL(link);
    HttpURLConnection huc=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    huc.setReadTimeout(5000);
    huc.setDoOutput(true);
    huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
    huc.connect();
}catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(ctx, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think a HttpConnection is a AsyncTask already. So, I think you're making a call to an AsyncTask inside another.

Comment: It's just a URLConnection with support for HTTP-specific features.